# Kotlin by viewModels not working with 2 way data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am using Android MVVM pattern and two way data binding in my application. I have a simple form with some `MutableLiveData` of string, and then a `MediatorLiveData` of boolean which checks if all fields are filled and enables or disables the button:

```
var name = MutableLiveData<String>()
var id = MutableLiveData<String>()
...
var isValid = MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
```

I am of course adding the sources to the `MediatorLiveData`.

My problem is that I'm initializing the viewmodel like this in my fragment:

```
private val viewModel: StudentViewModel by viewModels()
```

And since I'm not calling the viewmodel in my fragment code, this is not working:

```
<layout>
<data>
<variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.app.viewmodels.StudentViewModel"/>
</data>
...
<FloatingActionButton ...
android:enabled="@{viewModel.isValid}"
```

Before I was using Java and this worked, but I switched to Kotlin and I do not want to make the viewModel nullable and initialize it `onCreate`. Shouldn't this work out of the box or I am doing something wrong?

My `StudentViewModel` init method is not being called, nor the validation method of the `MediatorLiveData`. Of course the button is only one way binding since two way binding does not make sense on the `enabled` attribute of a button. The fields are two-way bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the lifecycle owner of the viewModel:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = YourBinding.bind(view)
        binding.apply {
            viewModel = mViewModel
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        }
    }
```

Where `mViewModel` is the variable you lazy initialized.